# How to debug gstreamer-java?

Tags: java, gstreamer

How do I debug GStreamer in java?

I have constructed a pipe, all links return an OK, but no packets leave the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something really useful myself:

http://groups.google.com/group/gstreamer-java/browse_thread/thread/f7956a4ec046c645/75d8c6f91cc4ee2b?lnk=gst&q=debug#75d8c6f91cc4ee2b